# Will Paginate Rails 3 Per Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I am trying to limit the number of elements returned with [mislav's will paginate](http://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/tree/rails3) with Rails 3. I am currently using:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'will_paginate', :git => 'git://github.com/mislav/will_paginate.git', :branch => 'rails3'

# company.rb
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.per_page = 8
end

# company_controller.rb
def index
  @companies = Company.where(...).paginate(:page => params[:page])
end
```

This does pagination, but not 8 items per page. If I modify the code to not use the "where" it works fine. However, adding "where" or "scoped" seems to cause issues. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ended up being forced to move the per page limit into the query. Appears to be a bug with the Rails 3 version. Thus, fixed using:

```
@companies = Company.where(...).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 8)
```

Comment: This was a bug. Now fixed! Use gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.pre4'

Answer (score 4):

@Kevin, if you want to be sure per_page is consistent across various queries you can use Company.per_page, eg.

```
@companies = Company.where(...).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => Company.per_page)
```

You may also give a try to Kaminari gem which is much better integrated with rails 3:   http://railscasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  paginates_per 7
end

@companies = Company.where(...).page(params[:page])
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using 'Companies' and not 'Company'.  This might just be a typo here but it appears to be an issue.