# kaminari: undefined method `paginate' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007f9933670ab0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, kaminari

In my controller, I have:

```
@bills = Bill.where(:param1 => x, :param2 => y).sort_by {|u| u.created_at}.reverse.paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

And I get the above-mentioned error when I try to render. Getting rid of the where, sort and reverse clauses gets rid of the problem but I need them. How can I have both?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `sort_by {|u| u.created_at}`, you fetch data from db to array and sort it in ruby side.

If you want paginate the ruby array data try this:

```
@bills = Kaminari.paginate_array(Bill.where(:param1 => x, :param2 => y)).page(params[:page]).per(PER_PAGE_RECORDS)`
```

but the better way sort yours data in the DB query

```
@bills = Bill.where(:param1 => x, :param2 => y).order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

Answer (score 0):

use AR chains. sort_by results in an array.

```
@bills = Bill.where(:param1 => x, :param2 => y).order('created_at DESC').paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the gem meta_search ([usage](http://railscasts.com/episodes/251-metawhere-metasearch)) in conjunction with the gem will_paginate ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095727/will-paginate-rails-3-per-page)). I think it could help you here.